# Qual è il significato di "teso" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Sommamente egli rifulgeva nella capacità di scrivere che dimostrò col suo unico *Cortegiano*, una vera bibbia sulla società delle nostre corti, libro un po' **teso** di pretese morali.

Questa frase fa riferimento a Baldesar Castiglione. Ho cercato il significato di "teso" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il suo senso nel passaggio precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Di scarsa utilità, ma ho l'impressione (che però non posso provare con fonti) che "teso" sia come "intessuto".

Answer (score 2):

Teso può assumere il significato di "Intensamente rivolto a un oggetto o a un fine determinato".

Questo romanzo utilizza una scrittura poco utilizzata ai giorni nostri visto che la protagonista visse negli anni del Rinascimento pure la scrittura è "vecchia".

Ritengo quindi plausibile che si potesse dire **teso di** anche se attualmente io (e anche i dizionari più rinomati) utilizzerei più il **teso a** se proprio dovessi usare teso.

Posso quindi dedurre che questo libro di cui si parla abbia come scopo quello di instillare nella mente del lettore una qualche morale, forse anche troppo presente